# Kids locked the door Then tried to open it without the knob...any advice that won’t cost me a door?

Tags: doors

[image]

I really can’t afford another door right now and I need this bathroom... can ya help a fella out?

Answer (score 3):

Take a screwdriver and put in in the hole on the left. That should give you enough leverage to retract the latch and open the door.

Replacing the doorknob is a pretty simple DIY job. Though you want to avoid the knob that can be pushed closed while locked to avoid a repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I turned the exposure way, way up so you can see the components clearly. 
[image]

The hole on the left is for the doorknob assembly to go through; it isn't anything.  Other than that, though, **something in there moves to release the latch**.  I suspect the silver bars in the middle move to the left, but poke around and you'll figure it out.  It may take a considerable amount of force.

Comment: I suspect they move to the *right* to retract the latch. The hole does nothing, +1.

Answer (score 0):

The lowest cost thing to do here is to remove the part of the old latch that comes out through the edge of the door. Then replace with a similar new door knob assembly. These are pretty standard so it should be relatively easy to install the knob unit. The cost of a new door knob assembly can be quite low, especially if you are not needing the highest quality..